# How to remove database columns from default asp.net mvc application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to learn asp.net and hence I want to create a project using default project that we get in visual studio > asp.net project > mvc project. I will customize it in bits and try to learn asp.net.

I ran it and registered a user and then I was able to open database explorer. Here there were many columns like "emailConfirmed" , "TwoFactorAuth" etc that I did not need, so I wanted to delete them. I deleted them from the database(localDB), but I keep getting errors like Invalid column name "emailConfirmed" etc. So how do I make sure that they are totally gone from my project for good. I believe they are there in some C# code somewhere, but I don't know in which file.

And also I have an extremely important question, probably a very silly question. Where is the code in that default project that tells that whenever I submit my form, my data should go into corresponding database columns? Basically what I mean is where is the code that says stuff like `SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)` etc.

Comment: Just leave the columns. If you don't want to use them, don't. There's no reason to delete them. .Net Identity takes care of the database calls. The only way you're going to see the DB calls and to get rid of the columns is to implement your own UserStore or create your own auth system

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks. I also have another related question. Say that I added another column called Gender to the default table and added necessary textboxes for the users to enter that information on register page. Now where I change the code that says that this information should go back to this database? Because now when I try to register, my database is only picking up the default values like email, password.

Comment: see my answer below. Please upvote and accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the columns. If you don't want to use them, don't. There's no reason to delete them. .Net Identity takes care of the database calls. The only way you're going to see the DB calls and to get rid of the columns is to implement your own UserStore or create your own authentication system.

To you second question:

You should add your new fields to `/Models/IdentityModels.cs` like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

From there you need to create a new Migration to push the change to the database. You really shouldn't modify the database schema (columns and tables) directly, you should do that from Code First